# Ensuring relationship integrity in a database modelling sets and subsets

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I have a model that consists in these 3 tables (among others):

```
Item
  PK id_item
Set
  PK id_set
Subset
  PK id_subset
```

- Each `Item` MUST belong to one and just one `Set` (1..N)
- You can define zero or more `Subsets` for each `Set` (0..N)
- Each `Item` belongs to zero or one subset (0..N)

Ive modelled the database adding the following FK:

```
Item
  PK id_item
  FK id_set
  FK id_subset 
Set
  PK id_set
Subset
  PK id_subset
  FK id_set
```

I cannot find a way to forbid the database to accept `Items` belonging to one `Set` (A) and to a `Subset` (B2) that belongs to a different `Set` (B).

Is there anyway to do so? Or is this just a bad design/modelling?

This is a SQL Server 2008 database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if an Item can belong to a subset, you must add a foreign key between the Item table and the subset table.

Second, add a check constraint on the Item table that will make sure that if the subset_id does not belong in the set_id, will raise an exception.

To do that, first you create a user defied function to test the values:

```
CREATE FUNCTION udf_CheckSubSet
(
    @id_set int,
    @id_subset int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    IF @id_subset IS NULL OR EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Subset
        WHERE id_subset = @id_subset
        AND id_set = @id_set
    )
    BEGIN
        RETURN 1
    END 
    -- logical else
    RETURN 0
END
```

then you create the check constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE Item
    ADD CONSTRAINT cc_Item_subset CHECK (dbo.udf_CheckSubSet(id_set, id_subset) = 1);
```

However, I also suggest to create a stored procedure to insert the item, and test inside the stored procedure before inserting the item.
The reason for this is that it's much more expensive (performance-wise) to handle exceptions then to simply test the input before inserting it to the table.

you might be wondering why do you even need the check constraint, if you already handle the problem with the stored procedure. The answer to this question is that the check constraint will not allow inserting updating the data in the table even if someone tries to do it directly from SSMS, or just write an insert or update statement.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the FK, I forgot to include it on the question. Just to be clear, I'm looking for a database-side solution

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** while it is possible to implement this kind of constraint using database schema alone, I strongly advise you against using the approach explained below in any real life project.

Academically speaking, in order to do what you want you have to migrate the identifying key from Set via both Set and Subset foreign keys. The schema will look like this:

```
use master;
go
if db_id('SampleDB') is not null
    set noexec on;
go
create database SampleDB;
go
use SampleDB;
go

/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: Sets                                                  */
/*==============================================================*/
create table dbo.[Sets] (
   [Id] int                  not null,
   [Name] varchar(50)          not null,
   constraint [PK_Sets] primary key (Id)
)
go
/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: SubSets                                               */
/*==============================================================*/
create table dbo.[SubSets] (
   [SetId] int                  not null,
   [SubsetId] int                  not null,
   [Name] varchar(50)          not null,
   constraint [PK_SubSets] primary key (SetId, SubsetId)
)
go

alter table dbo.SubSets
   add constraint FK_SubSets_Sets_SetId foreign key (SetId)
      references dbo.Sets (Id)
go

/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: Items                                                 */
/*==============================================================*/
create table dbo.[Items] (
   [Id] int                  not null,
   [SetId] int                  not null,
   [SubsetId] int                  null,
   [Name] varchar(50)          not null,
   constraint [PK_Items] primary key (Id)
)
go

alter table dbo.Items
   add constraint FK_Items_Sets_SetId foreign key (SetId)
      references dbo.Sets (Id)
go

alter table dbo.Items
   add constraint FK_Items_SubSets_SetIdSubsetId foreign key (SetId, SubsetId)
      references dbo.SubSets (SetId, SubsetId)
go

set noexec off;
go

use master;
go
```

As you can see, the PK on the dbo.Subset table is somewhat lame. It serves its purpose, of course, but it could have been made simpler. Another unusual thing is that SubsetId column in dbo.Items table participates in 2 foreign keys that point to different tables.

You can insert some data into this schema, and it will be perfectly fine:

```
insert into dbo.Sets (Id, Name)
values
    (1, 'Set 1'),
    (2, 'Set 2');
go

insert into dbo.SubSets (SetId, SubsetId, Name)
values
    (1, 1, 'Subset 1-1'),
    (1, 2, 'Subset 1-2');
go

insert into dbo.Items (Id, SetId, SubsetId, Name)
values
    (1, 1, 1, 'Banana'),
    (2, 1, 1, 'Plate'),
    (3, 1, 2, 'Charger'),
    (4, 1, null, 'Toothpick'),
    (5, 2, null, 'Cup');
```

And you will be hit with FK constraint violation when you try to add contradictory data, such as this:

```
insert into dbo.Items (Id, SetId, SubsetId, Name)
values
    (6, 2, 1, 'Fake t-shirt');
```

The subset 1 does not belong to the set 2, so the command above will not succeed.

Now - why you should never use this design approach, unless being forced to do so at the gunpoint:

- Not every business constraint can and should be implemented on the
  schema level. Actually, writing it down in the stored procedure will
  be easier to understand, maintain and work with, in most cases;
- It contains rarely used tricks which are very confusing and
  unexpected for most people, even seasoned database professionals. All
  of this add up to the cost of maintenance;
- Last but not least - queries that will work correctly with this kind
  of schema will be, how shall I put this, awkward and difficult to write. Also, you will most probably encounter a lot of problems it you will try to combine this schema with any kind of ORM. Or maybe not; or maybe they will only manifest themselves once being put in production, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was really interesting, although Zhoar's answer is more aligned with what I was looking for.