# Preserve data integrity in a database structure with two paths of association

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

I have this situation that is as simple as it is annoying.

The requirements are

1. Every `item` must have an associated `category`.
2. Every `item` **MAY** be included in a `set`.
3. `Sets` must be composed of `items` of the same `category`.
4. There may be several `sets` of the same category.

The desired logic procedure to insert new data is as following:

1. `Categories` are inserted.
2. `Items` are inserted. For each new `item`, a `category` is assigned.
3. `Sets` of `items` of the same `category` are created.

I'd like to get a design where data integrity between tables is ensured.

I have come up with the following design, but I can't figure out how to maintain data integrity.

[image]

If the relationship highlighted in yellow is not taken into account, everything is very simple and data integrity is forced by design: an item acquires a category only when it is assigned to a set and the category is given by the set itself.However, it would not be possible to have items not associated with a set but linked to a category and this is annoying.

I want to avoid using special "bridging sets" to assign a category to an item since it would feel hacky and there is no way to distinguish between real sets and special ones.

So I introduced the relationship in yellow. But now you can create sets of objects of different categories!

How can I avoid this integrity problem using only plain constraints (index, uniques, FK) in MySQL?

Also I would like to avoid triggers as I don't like them as it seems  a fragile and not very reliable way to solve this problem...

I've read about similar question like [How to preserve data integrity in circular reference database structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48764009/how-to-preserve-data-integrity-in-circular-reference-database-structure) but I cannot understand how to apply the solution in my case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might found a solution by looking at the answer from Roger Wolf to a similar situation here:
[Ensuring relationship integrity in a database modelling sets and subsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31426713/ensuring-relationship-integrity-in-a-database-modelling-sets-and-subsets)

Essentially, in the `items` table, I've changed the `set_id` FK to a composite FK that references both `set.id` and `set.category_id` from, respectively, `items.set_id` and `item.category_id` columns.

In this way there is an overlap of the two FKs on `items` table.
So for each row in `items` table, once a `category_id` is chosen, the FK referring to the `sets` table is forced to point to a set of the same category.
If this condition is not respected, an exception is thrown.

Now, the original answer came with an advice against the use of this approach.
I am uncertain whether this is a good idea or not.
Surely it works and I think that is a fairly elegant solution compared to the one that uses tiggers for such a simple piece of a a more complex design.
Maybe the same solution is more difficult to understand and maintain if heavily applied to a large set of tables.

**Edit:**
As AntC pointed out in the comments below, this technique, although working, can give insidious problems e.g. if you want to change the `category_id` for a `set`.
In that case you would have to update the `category_id` of each `item` linked to that `set`.
That needs BEGIN COMMIT/END COMMIT wrapped around the updates.

So ultimately it's probably not worth it and it's better to investigate the requirements further in order to find a better schema.

Comment: "came with an advice against the use of this approach". Yes for all the reasons that other answer warns about: you need a stored procedure, which affects performance; you need a more complex key structure. And you are still recording the same information in two places, so there's an opportunity for anomalies.

Comment: Think about data content maintenance: suppose the user wants to change the `category_id` for a `set`; now you have to UPDATE the `category_id` of every linked `item` at the same time. That needs BEGIN COMMIT/END COMMIT wrapped around the updates.

Comment: Thanks @AntC, now I see the complexity of update a `category_id` for a `set`. It's indeed a little bit wonky.... I don't think I will run into problem for my current project, but maybe I've to think again about requirements and come up with some better schema.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting scenario. I don't see a slam-dunk 'best' approach. One consideration here is: what proportion of `items` are in `sets` vs attached only to `categories`?

- What you don't want is two fields on `items`. Because, as you say, there's going to be data anomalies: an `item`'s direct `category` being different to the `category` it inherits via its `set`.
- Ideally you'd make a single field on `items` that is an Algebraic Data Type aka [Tagged Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), with a tag saying its payload was a `category` vs a `set`. But SQL doesn't support ADTs. So any SQL approach would have to be a bit hacky.
- Then I suggest the compromise is to make every `item` a member of a `set`, from which it inherits its `category`. Then data access is consistent: always `JOIN` `items-sets-categories`.
- To support that, create dummy `sets` whose only purpose is to link to a `category`.
- To address "there is no way to distinguish between real sets and special ones": put an extra field/indicator on `sets`: this is a 'real' set vs this is a link-to-category set. (Or a hack: make the `set-description` as "Category: <category-name>".)

**Addit:** BTW your "desired logic procedure to insert new data" is just wrong: you must insert `sets` (Step 3) before `items` (Step 2).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I might found a way to obtain what I need (see my answer)
For the logic procedure side, I dont' see anything wrong given the point 2 of requirements. The idea is to create sets from existing items and categories. So when a item is created its set_id FK will be null. This is indeed a little graphical error in the posted image.

Comment: "create sets from existing items and categories." So you have an existing schema that doesn't meet new/changed business requirements. And somebody wants you to kludge it. Perhaps because they think it will be less disruption? It won't: you/the IT team/and the users will pay for anomalies and awkward data maintenance over the long term.

Comment: fortunately for me is a new design and I'm free to change the schema as desired. Actually at this moment I'm the only developer for this project.
If you have some better idea for a schema that can meet this kind of requirements let me know!